# make directory and copy file on the go , python equivalent of cp -n in bash

Tags: python

I have a json file which i am parsing and it gives me some paths like - abc1/xyz2/file1.txt
I have to copy this file to one other location(for eg- /scratch/userdid/pp)

I know there is a bash equivalent of this
cp -n file.txt  --parents /scratch/userid/pp

and i can use this with os.system() in python and it creates the directory structure and copy the file in one go.

This is summerized script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def parse_json():
   //parse json file

def some():
    #get a list and create dirs = list length
    for i in len(list):
        dir = TASK + str(i)
        os.makedir(dir)
        path=abc1/xyz2/file1.txt
        os.system('cp -n path --parents /scratch/userid/pp')
```

This has to be done for several files and several times

i know this works, but i am looking for a more pythonic way(one liner may b) to do this
i tried

```
os.chdir(/scratch/userid/pp)
#split path to get folder and file
os.makedirs(path)
os.chdir(path)
shutil.copy(src, dest)
```

But there is a lot of makedirs and chdir involved for every file, as compared to one liner in bash

Answer (score 0):

You can use **shutil** from python directly, without OS package

example:

```
from shutil import copyfile
source_file="/home/user/file.txt"
destinaton_file="/home/user/folder/file.txt"
copyfile(source_file, destinaton_file)
```

You can use subprocess(python 3+) or commands(python 2+) also to execute copy shell commands in python